# Run at Debian startup

Tags: debian, startup

I want to launch a shell script every time Debian starts. It should start an application, amongst other things.

Where can I add this information?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the `init` system you use.

Stock Debian ships with `sysvinit` as default. If this is your case, write a startup script using `/etc/init.d/skeleton` as a template.

Make sure you give it the write owner, group and permissions. You also need to use `update-rc.d(8)` to activate the service for future restarts.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: put a line calling the script at the end of `/etc/rc.local`.

More complex solution: create a proper init script (/etc/init.d/....) and use `update-rc.d`  as the other answer suggests.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote on this. Debian provides and uses `/etc/rc.local`.